# Can't connect to EC2 instance via web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I'm a total newbie when it comes to servers and EC2 but I have an EC2 instance running which was stopped and restarted.  Since that I haven't been able to connect via a web-browser to the site but can connect via SSH.  Are there any ideas why this could be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the debug checklist:

- Check your server, make sure it is up and running in AWS management console.
- Check port security setting, from your local machine. If it is close open it in security group.

  ```
  telnet your_ip 80 # Check http port
  telnet your_ip 22 # Check SSH port
  ```
- Check your web server, Apache, Nginx, etc. If you cannot find your process, start it.

  ```
  ps -ef | grep -e nginx -e httpd -e apache
  ```
- Check your virtual host config, make sure you web server is listening to port 80 (http) or 443 (https).
- Run chkconfig and make sure your web server will start as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Check the security group in your instance property, it is probably allowing only SSH (default), you may want to add a inbound rule allowing HTTP traffic.

Comment: I have HTTP on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443 - is there anything else?

Comment: Is the service running from localhost?